# Linear Dependence or Something Else?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1 = (-5,-5,-2,9), v_2 = (-3,1,-3,1), v_3 = (6,8,1,3)$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. Find a vector $x$ such that $7(v_1 - x) + 7(v_2-x) = 4(v_3-x)$.

Can anyone give me a hint to start this?

Comment: Write $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Try to solve a system of equations, one for each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Start by distributing:

$$7v_1-7x+7v_2-7x=4v_3-4x$$

Now, solve for $x$ in terms of $v_1,v_2,v_3,$ then use the definitions of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ to figure out exactly what $x$ is.